# JSLint Strict Violation. Object Oriented Javascript frustrations

Tags: javascript, jslint, strict, use-strict

I'm trying to learn to do object oriented programming in JavaScript and getting JSLint strict violations. I understand that I'm using this in a non-global context (or something to that effect...), but I don't know how to do it properly. Here's my code:

```
function piece(color, type, x, y, captured, hasMoved) {
    "use strict";
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.captured = captured;
    this.hasMoved = hasMoved;

    this.movePiece = movePiece;
    function movePiece(x, y) {
        // if(isLegal(x, y, this.type){
            // this.x  =  x;
            // this.y  =  y;
        // }
         alert("you moved me!");
    }
}

var whitePawn1  =  piece("white", "pawn", 0, 1, false, false);
var blackBishop1  =  piece("black", "bishop", 8, 3, false, false);
```

Comment: What is the specific jslint message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use your `piece` function as a constructor—in other words call it with the `new` keyword.

<strike>As it stands now, `this` inside of your function is the global object.  Basically, instead of creating a new object, and adding properties to it, you're clobbering the gobal object with junk.</strike>

Since you're in strict mode, `this` will be undefined, so your code will error out.

This is what you want:

```
function Piece(color, type, x, y, captured, hasMoved) {
    "use strict";
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
    //...

var whitePawn1  = new Piece("white", "pawn", 0, 1, false, false);
var blackBishop1  = new Piece("black", "bishop", 8, 3, false, false);
```

Note that I renamed `piece` to start with a capital letter, since contructor functions by convention are supposed to.

---

Also, assuming a constructor function like this is really what you want, compared to Ian's answer, you should consider moving the `movePiece` function out to the function's prototype, so that function doesn't have to be re-created each and every time you create a new piece.  So this

```
this.movePiece = movePiece;
function movePiece(x, y) {
   //...
}
```

would become this

```
//this goes **outside** of your function
Piece.prototype.movePiece = function movePiece(x, y) {
       //...
}
```

Comment: I thought in strict mode, `this` was undefined unless you were calling the function through an object.  (ie: it's not the global object by default anymore.)

Comment: @cHao - it is, but, I think I'm saying this correctly, the function has to be *defined in* strict mode.  If you just say "use strict" inside of the function, then this is still window like usual.

Comment: Oh, it has to be inside a strict-mode script?

Comment: @cHao - gah, just tested it again.  I was wrong.  Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it would be different internally/functionally, but you could use:

```
function piece(color, type, x, y, captured, hasMoved) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        color: color,
        type: type,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        captured: captured,
        hasMoved: hasMoved
    };
}

var whitePawn1 = piece("white", "pawn", 0, 1, false, false);
```

Which doesn't require the use of `this` or `new`.

Although I guess you couldn't use the `.prototype` to apply a shared property/method to all instances. And the returned object initialization is extra too.

Answer (score 1):

Ah thanks Adam Rackis. That did it. For reference, here's my final JSLint verified code:

```
function Piece(color, type, x, y, captured, hasMoved) {
    "use strict";
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.captured = captured;
    this.hasMoved = hasMoved;
}
Piece.prototype.movePiece = function movePiece(x, y) {
    "use strict";
    /*global alert */
    alert("you moved me to " + x + ", " + y + "!");
};
var whitePawn1  =  new Piece("white", "pawn", 0, 1, false, false);
var blackBishop1  =  new Piece("black", "bishop", 8, 3, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `new` keyword before invoking your constructor. Code should look like this:

```
var whitePawn1    = new piece("white", "pawn", 0, 1, false, false);
var blackBishop1  = new piece("black", "bishop", 8, 3, false, false);
```

Also it is good patter to name constructor with capital letter, in your case `Piece`

Explanation: without `new` your constructors may corrupt the environment they where invoked at. The `new` creates the new environment and bind it to the constructor.